# JavaScript - Printing out each object in array which have same name?

Tags: javascript, arrays

So I have an array

```
var items = [];
items.push({
    name: "milk",
    id: "832480324"
});
  items.push({
    name: "milk",
    id: "6234312"
});
 items.push({
    name: "potato",
    id: "983213"
});
  items.push({
    name: "milk",
    id: "131235213"
});
```

Then I have a function `order(name, amount)`. If I call it like `order(milk, 2)` then it should show me 2 `ID's` of milk in the items array. How could I achieve that? (Yeah, I had to make a new question)

Comment: Why just 2 ID's (where name is 'milk') when you have 3 in your example?

Comment: how do you know which id(s) you want, the first 2, last 2?

Comment: I mean, not just 2 the number can be chosen by person. Example if he wants 3, then he chooses three and shows those 3 different id's. If 1 then one ID etc.

Comment: If he choose 1, should it be the first, the middle or the last? What is the criteria for selection? Also shouldn't it be `order("milk", 2)` - with strings?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use a [simple for loop](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for)

```js
var items = [];
items.push({
  name: "milk",
  id: "832480324"
});
items.push({
  name: "milk",
  id: "6234312"
});
items.push({
  name: "potato",
  id: "983213"
});
items.push({
  name: "milk",
  id: "131235213"
});

function order(name, count) {
  var res = [];
  // iterate over elements upto `count` reaches
  // or upto the last array elements
  for (var i = 0; i < items.length && count > 0; i++) {
    // if name value matched push it to the result array
    // and decrement count since one element is found
    if (items[i].name === name) {
      // push the id value of object to the array
      res.push(items[i].id);
      count--;
    }
  }
  // return the id's array
  return res;
}
console.log(order('milk', 2));
```

Answer (score 0):

A functional ES6 method that I like for its readability is to use `filter().map().slice()`:

```js
var items = [{name:"milk",id:"832480324"},{name:"milk",id:"6234312"},{name:"potato",id:"983213"},{name:"milk",id:"131235213"}];

function order(name, amount) {
  return items.filter(i => i.name === name)
              .map(i => i.id)
              .slice(0, amount);
}

console.log(order('milk', 2));
```